# Use custom driver for all new USB devices with same VID/PID

Tags: usb, labview, hid

In order to use my USB HID complient device with LabView, I had to create a custom USB driver. That works fine, except when I connect a new device (same VID&PID, different GUID) windows automaticly uses the standard hid.dll driver instead of my custom driver. Therefor the new device doesn't work with LabView until I manualy change the driver. Since this should be used in an semi-automated process, this manual driver change is not feasable.
Is there a way to tell windows to use my custom driver, whenever a device with the same VID and PID is connected? Or am I doing something else wrong?

edit:

Setupapi.app.log file after installing driver trough Driver Wizard 5.3:

```
>>>  [Build Driver List - USB\VID_0483&PID_1208&MI_01\8&35506E0F&1&0001]
>>>  Section start 2018/03/27 12:52:34.409
      cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\NIvisa\DriverWizardInstallInf64.exe"  C:\Users\LOCALA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\LVTEMP~1.TMP
     cpy: Policy is set to make all digital signatures equal.
<<<  Section end 2018/03/27 12:52:34.413
<<<  [Exit status: SUCCESS]


>>>  [Build Driver List - USB\VID_0483&PID_1208&MI_01\8&35506E0F&1&0001]
>>>  Section start 2018/03/27 12:52:34.413
      cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\NIvisa\DriverWizardInstallInf64.exe"  C:\Users\LOCALA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\LVTEMP~1.TMP
     cpy: Policy is set to make all digital signatures equal.
!    sig: Verifying file against specific (valid) catalog failed! (0x00000057)
!    sig: Error 87: The parameter is incorrect.
!    sig: Verifying file against specific Authenticode(tm) catalog failed! (0x80092003)
!    sig: Error 0x80092003: An error occurred while reading or writing to a file.
<<<  Section end 2018/03/27 12:52:34.421
<<<  [Exit status: SUCCESS]


>>>  [DIF_SELECTBESTCOMPATDRV - USB\VID_0483&PID_1208&MI_01\8&35506E0F&1&0001]
>>>  Section start 2018/03/27 12:52:34.422
      cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\NIvisa\DriverWizardInstallInf64.exe"  C:\Users\LOCALA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\LVTEMP~1.TMP
<<<  Section end 2018/03/27 12:52:34.423
<<<  [Exit status: SUCCESS]
```

.inf file created by Driver Wizard 5.3:

```
;===========================================================================
;  This file was generated using:
;  NI-VISA Driver Development Wizard version 5.3
;===========================================================================
;
;  This file is for use with Windows 8/7/Vista. This will not work on Windows
;  XP.  This Windows Setup Information File contains the information
;  NI-VISA needs in order to access your instrument.  Do not modify the
;  contents of this file unless you are sure about what you are doing.
;
;===========================================================================
;
;  Windows Vista/7 Installation:
;  To apply the contents of this file to a system's settings, right-click
;  this file and choose "Install". If the device was plugged in before this
;  file is installed, the device will need to be removed from the "Unknown
;  Devices" class in the Windows Device Manager.
;
;===========================================================================
;
;  Windows 8 Installation:
;  To apply the contents of this file to a system's settings, a catalog file
;  must be generated and signed using either a personal certificate or a
;  certificate obtained from a Certificate Authority (CA).  For detailed
;  instructions on how to install your INF on Windows 8, visit
;  http://ni.com/info and enter the Info Code INFWin8.
;
;===========================================================================
;
;  Removal:
;  At installation, Windows copies the file into the %SystemRoot%\inf
;  directory using the alternate filename oem##.inf.  You may have
;  to search all the files to find the one from which this is copied.
;  Remove that file and its associated .pnf file (if it exists) from
;  %SystemRoot%\inf.  Either reboot the computer, or perform a
;  "Scan for hardware changes" from the Windows Device Manager.
;
;===========================================================================
    [Version]
    Signature=$WINDOWS NT$
    Class=visaUsbDevice
    ClassGUID={A3330EDF-239D-4206-833B-1D58952613D5}
    Provider=%Vendor0%
    DriverVer=03/26/2018,1.0
    CatalogFile=JumpSensor.cat

    ;===========================================================================
    ;  Default Installer
    ;===========================================================================

    [DefaultInstall]
    CopyINF=JumpSensor.inf

    [DestinationDirs]

    [SourceDisksNames]

    [SourceDisksFiles]

    ;===========================================================================
    ;  Class Installer
    ;===========================================================================

    [ClassInstall32]
    AddReg=AddClass_AddReg

    [AddClass_AddReg]
    HKR,,,0,%DeviceClassString%
    HKR,,Icon,,"-20"

    ;===========================================================================

    [Manufacturer]
    %Vendor1%=USBList,NTamd64

    [USBList]
    %USB\VID_0483&PID_1208&MI_00.DeviceDesc%=WinUsb_Inst, USB\VID_0483&PID_1208&MI_00
    %USB\VID_0483&PID_1208&MI_01.DeviceDesc%=WinUsb_Inst, USB\VID_0483&PID_1208&MI_01

    [USBList.NTamd64]
    %USB\VID_0483&PID_1208&MI_00.DeviceDesc%=WinUsb_Inst, USB\VID_0483&PID_1208&MI_00
    %USB\VID_0483&PID_1208&MI_01.DeviceDesc%=WinUsb_Inst, USB\VID_0483&PID_1208&MI_01

    [PreCopySection]
    HKR,,NoSetupUI,,1

    [WinUsb_Inst]
    Include = winusb.inf
    Needs = WINUSB.NT

    [WinUsb_Inst.hw]
    AddReg=WinUsb_Inst_HW_AddReg

    [WinUsb_Inst.Services]
    Addservice = WinUsb, 0x00000002, WinUsb_AddService

    [WinUsb_AddService]
    DisplayName    = %WinUsb_Service_DisplayName%
    ServiceType    = %SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER%
    StartType      = %SERVICE_DEMAND_START%
    ErrorControl   = %SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL%
    ServiceBinary  = %12%\WinUSB.sys

    [WinUsb_Inst_HW_AddReg]
    HKR,,DeviceInterfaceGUIDs, 0x10000,"{761ED34A-CCFA-416b-94BB-33486DB1F5D5}"

    [Strings]
    Vendor0="STMicroelectronics"
    Vendor1="STMicroelectronics"
    USB\VID_0483&PID_1208&MI_00.DeviceDesc="JUMP Sensor"
    USB\VID_0483&PID_1208&MI_01.DeviceDesc="JUMP Sensor"
    DeviceClassString="NI-VISA USB Devices"
    WinUsb_Service_DisplayName="WinUSB Driver"

    SERVICE_BOOT_START = 0x0
    SERVICE_SYSTEM_START = 0x1
    SERVICE_AUTO_START = 0x2
    SERVICE_DEMAND_START = 0x3
    SERVICE_DISABLED = 0x4

    SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER = 0x1
    SERVICE_ERROR_IGNORE = 0x0
    SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL = 0x1
    SERVICE_ERROR_SEVERE = 0x2
    SERVICE_ERROR_CRITICAL = 0x3
```

Comment: Did you make and install a .inf file for your driver?  Can you post it here?  What do you mean by "different GUID"? Is the GUID really just the USB device's "serial number" string descriptor?

Comment: Yes installed the .inf file trough NI-VISA Driver Wizard 5.3, which also created the .inf file for me. The driver is then used by all devices, that were connected during the installation process. The different GUID part was refering to the different USB serial number.

Comment: OK, do you actually have JumpSensor.cat in the same directory as the INF file, and is it signed?  Driver packages need a signed CAT file to be installed on Windows 8 and later, even if they contain no kernel-mode code.  Lots of info here: http://www.davidegrayson.com/signing   If you don't want to buy a certificate you should be able to make one with OpenSSL and install it as a trusted root certificate authority on your computer but it will require some tinkering; I haven't written that article yet :-)

Comment: FYI you can install that driver just by right-clicking the .inf file and selecting "Install", no need for a wizard.